# Why my button listener does not invoke anything except print method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I dont know why, any way to pass method into Unity button OnClick listener, wont work, except simple printing, in other case when i want print for example current Tile position its again dont do nothink...

There is no errors in console. Button respond, no problem with layers too

Only way to make this action is invoke on tile start ( not intened ;d )
I never before seen somethink like that, often its because you add listener to prefab 'before' attaching him, but not now. and why the heck, i can print only text nothink else, its kinda weird hah.

```
public class Bomb_Tile : TileCell, IDestroyable
{
    public GameObject ImageIcon;
    public Bomb_Tile(TileCell data) : base(data)
    {
        Position = data.Position;
        GameManager.instance.Bombs.Add(data.Position, this);

        PlaceOnCell();

        // Testing method on start => and working correct / but its should be attach to button
        // Activate());
    }

    public void PlaceOnCell()
    {
        ImageIcon = Instantiate(GameManager.instance.BombIcon, Transform);
        Button btn = ImageIcon.GetComponent<Button>();

        // case 0 ( assign simplest string print method ) = WORK !?
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => print("string"));

        // case 1 (attempt to assign other print function) = Dont work.
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => print(data.Position));

        // case 2 (normal way to assign desired method to trigger here) = Dont work.
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => Activate());

        // case 3 ( trying to attempt this method from object list in GM class ) = Dont work.
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => GameManager.instance.Bombs[Position].Activate());
    }

    public void Activate()
    {
        print("bomb activation -> simple swap image to explosion");
        Destroy(ImageIcon);
        // Swap to explosion icon
        ImageIcon = Instantiate(GameManager.instance.ExplosionImage, Transform);
    }
}
```

Sorry, its my first question because no hope with searching for the answer hah ;x

Comment: Are you saying that either of the print commands work alone but not together? What happens if you comment out "ImageIcon = ..." line and try printing both things again?

Comment: I tried: Instantiate object with button, or add button after = in both cases same result, i cant assign nothing else to reguular print string method. I also tried assign this to external button not attached to image, tried remove incheritance from base monobehaviour clas, and instance object with attached script itself , whats going on its simple button and looks it dont see anything xD, PS. invoking action from Gamemanagerclass from list of bombs works fine, but i want to invoke by clicking exact image button , hmm

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, it's just that there are 3 print statements in your code and I still don't fully understand which ones don't work together. My assumption is that Activate's print ALWAYS works? Then, either `print("elo")` works or `print(data.Position)` works but NOT BOTH? If you remove `print("elo")`, `print(data.Position)` WORKS, if you remove `print(data.Position)`, `print("elo")` WORKS?

Comment: oh, yes its my fault i should type this other way. basically i want only trigger `Activate()`  by pressing button, other "examples" there is only for check where its dont work. to be clear, non of attempts to assign any function except `print(string)` no matter if its together or not work. Only way to acces `Activate()" is manual trigger from GameManager class. but i cant assign this on button from Bomb class

Comment: If you add only this listener, what is the output in console (make sure that all log types are active in Console, i.e. make sure errors aren't hidden from console): `btn.onClick.AddListener(() => 
{
print("string");
print("before data position");
print(data.Position);
print("before activate");
Activate();
print("after activate");
});`

Comment: empty, no logs, no warnings, its seems block it if i want touch any class variable, or methods? its block enterly click triggered method , i wll do this different way maybe spawn buttons when they need insteed add them to object once at start , -.- there is something wrong ,

Comment: It is **impossible** for `btn.onClick.AddListener(() => print("string"));` to work but not my code. That must be something on your end. I can't debug this issue any further.

Comment: When I remove any class based parameters and leave only 3x print string then its work properly , problem occurs when added  something from base class or bomb class inside button call then button dont print log at all... okay time for rewrite this . Btw thank for trying help

Comment: That's really strange. Hope you find a solution. Please let us know if you find the culprit.

Comment: included code won't compile, `TileCell` is undefined. Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Comment: @MrKomugiko: Kindly do check if you have selected Errors in Console windows, just to be sure that they will actually get printed on the Console Window. Might can be the case that you have only selected Info/Debug in Console window, and warning/errors are unselected, so you are not getting any outputs in case some Error/Warning comes.